# Problems with importing a .txt file

Tags: import

I have some problems with importing a .txt file as a table. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/data.txt) is the file. I tried importing it with

```
data = Import["data.txt", "Data"]
```

I want to access single values, but it doesn't work with my import. I can't access `data[[2, 1]]` for example to get the first value in `data[[2]]` and so on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
xxx = Import["C:\\Users\\Rasher\\Downloads\\data.txt", "Data"];
zzz = xxx // StringSplit;
zzz[[2, 2]]
```

Gives 774...

You need to decide how / where to "split" or do other operations, since this is basically a bulk text file, e.g., split at line-breaks, etc. Read the documentation on `StringSplit` and ancillary text manipulation functions, once you've imported it these will let you massage it into the desired *MMA* list/array structure.

With just the above, row 1 of zzz is what appear to be the column headings, so `zzz[[1,n]]` gets you the n'th one. Row 2 to ... are the rows, with the first entry the row name, e.g, `zzz[[2,1]]` gets the name of the first row under headings, `zzz[[2,2]]` the first row entry, etc.

Comment: Ahh StringSplit, of course. Works fine now..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that does it for you in one go:

```
data = ReadList["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/data.txt", Word,
               RecordLists -> True];
```

So that:

```
data[[2, 2]]
```

gives `774`